# How to get OriginatingClientIPAddress from headers?

Tags: ip-address, request-headers, x-forwarded-for

How can I auto read X-Forwarded-For from header without asking the permissions?

The problem I'm facing right now is, users are hitting my website through a third party server, as a result when I am requesting for the ip I'm getting the ip of the proxy server, not the original client's ip.I can get it from x-forwarded-for field, but how to get it without x-forwarded-for field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking for is a well established way of performing *Denial of service* attacks.

> Changing the IP of the request from your third party server won't help you because then you won't be able to get a response from your website as your website would then send the response to the ip from where the request originated (to the website).

That being said, you **have** to use the **x-forwarded-for** field and as a matter of fact that's the sole reason for this header to exist.

---

**SOLUTION**

> When the third party server receives a **request** (original) you need to set the *x-forwarded-for* header of the **new request** (generated) to that of the IP of the (original) request. So when you send the (generated) request to your website, use the *x-forwarded-for* header to collect the IP of the (original) request.

Hope that made sense :)